# New to solidity, why is it not returning my integer?

Tags: solidity

I recently started learning solidity, and have written a very basic contract, but it is not returning my integer and I am not sure why:

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

```
uint256 favouriteNumber; //This will get initialised as 0, as it is not specified

function store(uint256 _favouriteNumber) public {
    favouriteNumber = _favouriteNumber;

}

function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
    return favouriteNumber;
}
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDazh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the number on the textbox, you must to click over the orange button called `store` and after this operation you can click on the `retrieve` button.

Comment: thank you so much, I can't believe I didnt realise that. it all makes so much sense now

Comment: Please, select my answer as accepted to help other person who have the same problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When you add your value in store, there will be downward arrow, I think you are not clicking the transact button. I have tested your smart contract and it is perfectly fine. [check the transact button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXPYj.png).

Comment: thank you. someone else said this yesterday and I can't believe I just didnt click store. I have a lot to learn ig